# Why are linked objects from another file laggy, and same objects are fast when appended?

Tags: performance, append, memory-management

I have a laggy file that will take up to 12 seconds to select a basic object and take up to 14gb of memory, to fix this I open a new blend file and append all the objects and now there is no delay and only takes up 3gb of memory, despite they contain the exact same objects that I thought would be causing the lag in the first place and the renders are identical.

Is there a cache file or something I'm missing that I can just delete instead? Its getting a little tedious constantly doing this.

Comment: You could have changed some viewport settings that simplify the scene for fast viewing, or there is a lot of duplicate/orphaned data sitting in the old file.

Comment: Try File > Cleanup > Unused Data Blocks in the laggy file.